# Inherit implementation of nested template class

Tags: c++, templates, nested

my problem is a little bit weird and I'm not able to find an answer to it.

1) I do have a nested template class for my protocol

```
    template <template<class TMessage> class TFrame, class TMessage>
    class Protocoll
    {
      ...
    }
```

2) I do have an implementation for my frame and message

```
    class MessageImpl : public Message
    {
      ...
    }

    class FrameImpl : public Frame<MessageImpl>
    {
      ...
    }
```

3) Now I want to implement my protocol using the implementations for frame and message.

```
    class ProtocolImpl : public Protocol<FrameImpl, MessageImpl>
    {
      ...
    }
```

The compiler complains about the first template Parameter "FrameImpl", because it is (obviously) no generic template type any more.

Is there any possibility to make this compile?
I don't want to make my 'FrameImpl' generic/template because than I would need to implement it in the header.

Thanks a lot

**Edit:**

Because of requesting a complete sample:

```
    //--------------------- definitions

    class Message
    {
    public:
      virtual ~Message() = default;
      virtual void foo() noexcept = 0;
    };

    template <class Message>
    class Frame
    {
    public:
      virtual ~Frame() = default;
      virtual void foo() noexcept = 0;
    };

    template <template<class TMessage> class TFrame, class TMessage>
    class Protocol
    {
    public:
      virtual ~Protocol() = default;
      virtual void foo() noexcept;
    };

    //--------------------- implementations

    class MessageImpl : public Message
    {
    public:
      void foo() noexcept
      { }
    };

    class FrameImpl : public Frame<MessageImpl>
    {
    public:
      FrameImpl()
      :  message{ }
      { }

      void foo() noexcept
      { 
        message.foo();
      }
    private:
      MessageImpl message;
    };

    class ProtocolImpl : public Protocol<FrameImpl, MessageImpl>
    {

    };
```

in the declaration of "ProtocolImpl", I could pass Frame as template type, but not FrameImpl.

Comment: Can you provide us with a [MCVE] reproducing your problem please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do

```
template <typename>
using FrameImplT = FrameImpl;

class ProtocolImpl : public Protocol<FrameImplT, MessageImpl>
{
   // ...
};
```

But think at what is the purpose of those template parameters.